# AJAX xmlhttprequest popup

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Basically, what I'm trying to do is have a fade in/out popup in the corner of my page. e.g. John Doe has just come online. I'm using AJAX to check for the latest updates, if they are new, display the popup.

the function to display popup (using jquery) is:

```
function hidepop(){
  $("#popup").fadeOut("slow");
}

function showpop(){
  $("#popup").fadeIn("slow");
  setTimeout("hidepop()",4000);
}
```

The code to update and show the popup, if necessary, is:

```
function getHTTPObject(){
  if (window.ActiveXObject) return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest();
  else {
    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX. Please download Google Chrome or Firefox.");
    return null;
  }
} 


function checkUpdates(old){
  httpObject = getHTTPObject();
  var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
  if (httpObject != null) {
    link = "updates.php?rnd="+randomnumber;
    httpObject.open("GET", link , true);
    httpObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(httpObject.readyState == 4){
        var response = httpObject.responseText;
        var objDiv = document.getElementById("popup");
        objDiv.innerHTML = response;
        if(response == old){
          var time = setTimeout(function(){checkUpdates(response); response = null},5000);
        }else{
          var objDiv = document.getElementById("popup");
          objDiv.innerHTML = response;
          showpop();
          var time = setTimeout(function(){checkUpdates(response); response = null},5000);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, to start it all off:

```
onload="checkUpdates('');"
```

on the body tag.

So, my problem is... nothing happens.  I know that showing the popup works because if I call showpop() it will show.

This is probably some stupid mistake but, could you please give me some ideas/pointers to what the problem might be and how to fix it.

Thank you very much,
Calum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by using jquery's '[get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)' method, since you seem to be using jquery already.

```
var old = '';
function checkUpdates() {
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    link = "updates.php?rnd=" + randomnumber;
    $.get(link, function(data) {
        /* called when the resource was successfully retrieved */
        if (old != data) {
            $('#popup').html(data); // set the new data in the popup element
            showpop();              // show the popup
            old = data;             // store the retrieved data
        }
        setTimeout(checkUpdates, 5000);
    });
}
```

Your showpop and hidepop functions are not really defined correct.
Maybe you could read up on [document.ready(...)](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

This should do the trick (notice that with jquery's [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function you can nicely chain everything:

```
function hidepop(){
    $("#popup").fadeOut("slow");
}

function showpop(){
    $("#popup").fadeIn("slow");
    setTimeout(function() {hidepop();}, 4000);
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to be working, where is the 'response' variable coming from? thanks for your help.

Comment: That did the trick! although i did add the original showpop() back because your one wouldn't fade out again. thankyou so much. :)

Comment: glad to help :)
Does anyone know what's wrong with my hidepop? :)